# ZoneDateTime object getting defaulted to UTC

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time, zoneddatetime

Hi I have a date object in my controller request mapping. The object is of ZoneDateTime. The problem is on parsing the data to ZoneDateTime it is converting it to UTC by default. I need to retain the timezone information. Is there a way to handle that.

```
 ex: 2018-06-10T12:00:00+0500
```

value in my controller:

```
 2018-06-10T07:00:00[UTC]
```

I am planning to use an object mapper to fix it while marshaling of data in controller. But i am not sure if i am heading to right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use the [java-ee] tag when you have a question about a class in the Java SE API, simply because that class is clearly not part of Java EE API.

Comment: Without code I’ve got no idea, sorry. Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 2):

The string you're parsing doesn't have time zone information. The appropriate type to use is `OffsetDateTime`:

```
OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-06-10T12:00:00+0500", 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"))
```

You can convert that to a `ZonedDateTime` by calling `dt.toZonedDateTime()`.